# MODUL grequests, How GET simple print URL and Response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grequests

anyone can please explain me how i can split results for get just simple url and response?
I have try so many time but nothing, for now i can print just like:

```
50
0.4110674999999999
........, [<Response [200]>], [<Response [200]>], [<Response [200]>]]
[......, ['http://example.com.com/catalogue/page-48.html'], ['http://example.com.com/catalogue/page-49.html'], ['http://example.com.com/catalogue/page-50.html']]
```

I need like

```
<Response [200]>
https://example.com/
```

Thanks so much.

Ps. Also why after installing module grequests I get  this message on the console

```
C:\P3\lib\site-packages\grequests.py:22: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util.ssl_ (C:\\P3\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py)', 'urllib3.util (C:\\P3\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\__init__.py)'].
  curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

How I can fix it ? Uninstall complete python, install some patch or what ?
Thanks!

```
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def get_urls():
    urls = []
    for x in range(1,51):
        urls.append(f'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{x}.html')
    return urls

def get_data(urls):
    reqs = [grequests.get(link) for link in urls]
    resp = grequests.map(reqs)
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    urls = get_urls()
    url = len(get_urls())
    resp = get_data(urls)
    respo = len(get_data(urls))
    fin = time.perf_counter() - start

    resp_list = resp
    chunked_resp = list()
    chunk_size = respo
    urls_list = urls
    chunked_url = list()
    chunk_size = url

    print(urls)
    print(url)
    print(resp)
    print(respo)
    print(fin)  

    resp_list = resp
    chunked_resp = list()
        chunk_size = 1


    for i in range(0, len(resp_list), chunk_size):
        chunked_resp.append(resp_list[i:i+chunk_size])
    print(chunked_resp) 

    urls_list = urls
    chunked_url = list()
        chunk_size = 1


    for i in range(0, len(urls_list), chunk_size):
        chunked_url.append(urls_list[i:i+chunk_size])
    print(chunked_url)
```

Comment: Well, why do you have code that uses a list and `grequests.map()` if you only need one request and its response?

Comment: Thanks, so much for a info !! I have get a solution for the url, but for a response still nothing "TypeError: can only join an iterable", maybe can u tell me how edit this?

Answer (score 0):

OK i have get a solution only for print url:

```
def get_data(urls):
    reqs = [grequests.get(link) for link in urls]
    resp = grequests.get(reqs)
    return resp
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    urls = get_urls()
    resp = get_data(urls)
    resp = '\n'.join(resp)
    url = '\n'.join(urls)

http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-48.html
http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-49.html
http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-50.html

     resp = '\n'.join(resp)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

But for a resp i get TypeError: can only join an iterable

Ps. i am started learn python max 1  month... :(

Comment: Do you understand each line of your code? If not, you'll need to backtrack in your studies until you do.

Comment: unfortunately I can't afford any courses, I'm learning by myself slowly. Self-taught :(

Comment: I didn't tell you you'd need a course. For example, have you [worked through the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to get acquainted with the language's features?

Comment: I work as an ambulance rescuer, private life = 0.
In the few free hours I try to learn, but I haven't reached everything yet.

Comment: Also i have try

resp = sorted(get_data(urls))
    resp = '-'.join(resp)
    print(resp)

but TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable other error  :/